# Каким образом складывается общая ширина блока?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать лишний фрагмент в `class="actions"`Есть основная ширина, обусловленная самой кнопкой, а ещё справа фрагмент, из-за чего общая ширина становится больше.
[image: изображение]
[учебный сайт с этой проблемой](http://ca99378.tmweb.ru/)

```
<div class="block block-subscribe">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Newsletter') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
            <div class="form-subscribe-header">
                <label for="newsletter"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
               <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Sign up for our newsletter')) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Subscribe')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос html и css которые используются

Answer (score 1):

Длина `.actions` указана в процентах `width: 34.375%;`.
А у самой кнопки стоит `float:left;`

Вам следует убрать `float:left` и изменить JS, который устанавливает процентную длину у блоков `.actions` и `.input-box`

Comment: Благодарю!!! Подскажите, пожалуйста, по каким словам искать в js строки, отвечающие за это?

Comment: Вообще-то, как оказалось, это прописано напрямую в css файлах. `styles.css` строки в районе 4099 и 4104

Comment: Да, до вопроса проверил это и пробовал удалять ширину у обоих в процентах. Там получается нестыковка в том, что ширина кнопки складывается от ширины слова + паддинг. И по идее надо, чтобы эта кнопка ровнялась по правому краю, а `.input-box` прижимался к ней и подстраивал ширину учитывая ширину кнопки и их общей ширины. В общем пока не ясно как это можно сделать. js не понимаю к чему там и что делает.

Comment: И `float:left` удалял, но тогда между ними становится промежуток.